# Ramanujan-Petersson conjecture at various cusps

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Suppose that $f \in S_k(\Gamma_0(N)) $ be a Hecke eigenform whose Fourier expansion at $ i\infty $ is given by

$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda(n) n^{\frac{k-1}{2}} \exp(2\pi i n z),
$$

normalized so that $\lambda(1)=1$. In this setting the Ramanujan-Petersson conjecture states that $ |\lambda(n)| \leq d(n) $ the number of divisors of $n$ (for all $ n $ coprime to the level $ N $).

Does the same bound hold if I consider the Fourier expansion of $f$ at some other cusp?

Comment: Note that for oldforms the first Fourier coefficient might vanish, in which case the normalization you indicate is impossible. At any rate, even for newforms, I am sure the answer to your question is "no". Check out the following paper by Goldfeld, Hundley, and Lee: Fourier expansions of GL(2) newforms at various cusps.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look...

Comment: @GH: I haven't looked at the paper you mention, but I do not understand your claim: the expansion at a cusp corresponds to the expansion of a form on the conjugate congruence group $\gamma^{-1}\Gamma_0(N)\gamma$, for which the R-P conjecture is true.

Comment: @HenriCohen: I think the various Fourier expansions don't even obey the Hecke multiplicativity relations (for general $N$). Classical Hecke operators focus on the cusp $\infty$. Check out the abstract of the suggested article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.0028

Comment: Note that if the cusp is a so-called *Atkin-Lehner* cusp and the eigenform $f$ is a newform, then the Fourier expansion about that cusp *is* multiplicative and is essentially the same as the Fourier expansion at $\infty$ up to multiplication by an *Atkin-Lehner eigenvalue*, which necessarily has absolute value $1$. In particular, the Ramanujan conjecture at Atkin-Lehner cusps for newforms is equivalent to the Ramanujan conjecture at the cusp at $\infty$.

Comment: Even if not multiplicative, one should still have $|\lambda(n)|\le C.d(n)$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries can you give me a reference for Atkin-Lehner cusp. A google search did not return anything useful...

Comment: I am still a student, but my intuition aligns with @HenriCohen. If it is indeed the case that I am wrong, I would be very interested in understanding what makes the Fourier expansion at infinity so special.

Comment: Also, @HenriCohen, I presume the constant $C$ is absolute...

Comment: See https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01390245. These cusps are just (equivalent to ones) of the form $1/N_1$, where $N_1 \mid N$ and $(N_1, N/N_1) = 1$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries I think this actually connects to a paper of Asai, which was mentioned in the first reference of GH... Asai's paper : doi.org/10.2969/jmsj/02810048

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The estimate $|\lambda(n)| \leq C_N d(n)$ remains valid at all cusps, but $C_N$ cannot in general be taken independent of $N$.  See Remark 3.14 of [this paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3110797) ([arxiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5534)), where it is noted that for certain $(N,f,n)$, with $f$ a newform, one can have $\lambda(n) \gg n^{1/4}$ at some cusp.  (One can take for $n$ a suitable power of a prime $p$ for which $p^2 | N$.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the reference. I have a question though. It seems that $C_N$ depends only on $N$, and therefore the estimate $|\lambda(n)| \gg n^{1/4}$, if at all true can hold for finitely many $n$ dependent on $N$. Am I correct? In particular in Remark 3.14 of the reference, you have a bound on $k$ for which the Ramanujan bound may not hold for $\lambda(p^k)$. For larger $k$ does the Ramanujan conjecture hold?

Comment: Indeed, there are only finitely many values of $\gcd(n,N)$ (depending on $N$) for which such a lower bound can hold.